# Why is my DEM (digital elevation model) showing NA values when imported into R?

Tags: r, gis, geospatial, raster, na

When I import my DEM (digital elevation model) into R, it shows `NA` values instead of actual numbers for the elevations.

I can go into QGIS, use the Identify tool, and when I click on pixels, I get elevation values.

The DEM I am attempting to use has been merged, but again, QGIS says there are elevation values present.  I have imported other (smaller) DEMs with no issue, but the merged DEM I am using does not show any elevation values, according to R.  It is stopping me from doing any spatial analysis on the DEM.

I have also imported a landuse raster and it doesn't seem to have any issues so I am stumped.

Any insight would be very helpful, thank you!

**EDIT**

I am including a screenshot of the output from the `View()` function: it is how I know there are `NA` values instead of real numbers in the DEM in R.

[Here is the link to the View() function results screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EAO2.jpg)

Apologies if I am unclear - I am very new to R.

Comment: Can you please improve your question? For example, show the minimal R code to reproduce the problem and show how you determined that the values are `NA`.

Comment: I am not sure how to give you code to reproduce the problem...the DEM is a file on my computer so obviously I can't give you that.  I posted a screenshot, but that may not be enough.  I apologize, I am new at all this!

Comment: You might also consider posting in the GIS Stack Exchange https://gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Your interpretation of what you see with View is not correct --- perhaps first study some tutorials for spatial data in R. For raster data see `rspatial.org`